# IE6 "automatically" adds background color?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I came across a css problem encountered in **IE6**.

The `.ci_title` class displays a grey background color strangely, while in Chrome,FF and other modern browsers it is transparent.

I added `background-color:transparent` to `.ci_title` but it doesn't work.

The css rules are in [this file](http://s2.pinglun.la/md/css/cb_base.css) on **line 322**.

Here is the [demo](http://www.pinglunla.com/comment_box?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinglunla.com%2Fdemo&pt=%E6%8F%90%E5%8D%87%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%94%20%E7%A4%BE%E4%BC%9A%E5%8C%96%E8%AF%84%E8%AE%BA%E7%B3%BB%E7%BB%9F%E8%AF%84%E8%AE%BA%E5%95%A6%20-%20%E8%AF%84%E8%AE%BA%) link

Answer (score 3):

IE6 does not handle transparency natively. These guys will help you out with transparency: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can add `background-color: none;` instead.

Comment: I don't think IE6 cannot handle transparency. I added the transparent rule in `IE tester` using `My DebugBar`. It works. So anything mysterious happens?

Comment: I've never seen `background-color:transparent` work on IE6 so it might be that css rule specifically does not work. Actually, I have tried using this rule on several occasions and could never get it to do anything, regardless of the browser. Would my suggestion of clearing the background work in your case?

Comment: Thanks, @skashi. I am not able to modify the code now, because code is on remote server and I am not in charge of it. I will inform you as soon as code is modified.